# Incorrect mimetypes of a docx/pptx made with Pages/Keynote

Tags: php, symfony, powerpoint, mime-types, docx

I have a Symfony 2.7 project.

Recently I have complaints that clients cannot upload `.pptx` nor `.docx` files anymore.

After a bit of research it turned out to be the mimetype that I'm checking in order to prevent unwanted files to be uploaded.

`.pptx` and `.docx` files made by Power Point and Word are uploaded correctly and have correct mimetype (`application/vnd.ms-powerpoint` and `application/msword`), but the ones that are created in Pages and Keynote and then exported into `.docx`/`.pptx` have a mimetype of `application/octet-stream` or `application/zip` (depending on Symfony's MimeTypeGuesser used). By default the `FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser` is being used, it internally calls `finfo` to return `application/octet-stream`. The second guesser, `FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser`, returns `application/zip` (that one uses `file --mime` I believe).

Also when I run `file --mime` on those files (both on my Vagrant which is CentOS 7 and on my Mac), I get those results:

Vagrant:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ file --mime keynote_pptx_test.pptx
keynote_pptx_test.pptx: application/zip; charset=binary

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ file --mime powerpoint_pptx_test.pptx
powerpoint_pptx_test.pptx: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint; charset=binary
```

Local:

```
user@MacBook-Pro $ file --mime keynote_pptx_test.pptx
keynote_pptx_test.pptx: application/zip; charset=binary

user@MacBook-Pro $ file --mime powerpoint_pptx_test.pptx
powerpoint_pptx_test.pptx: application/zip; charset=binary
```

Obviously I DO NOT want to enable `application/zip` for uploading for security reasons.

The default mime type guesser (`FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser`) returns `application/octet-stream`. I'm not sure if I want to enable that mimetype for upload, also for security reasons.

Is there anything I can do to make those uploads happen, like check for mimetype differently (maybe there are more guessers in Symfony?), or should I enable `application/octet-stream` (if so, what are the security implications), or is it just Apple's software thing that needs to be improved on their side?

Comment: As the name imples, MimeTypeGuesser is just "guessing" the MimeType. From my experience it is really difficult to get the right mime type for files coming from many different sources, so you will need to end up opening the range of types that you accept. If you are worried about security , you can always apply more tests to those files, for example use a docx parser to verify that it is a real docx file

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I guess if there are not going to be any better options I will have to go with accepting `application/octet-stream` and parse like you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [Carlos Granados](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1557651/carlos-granados) is the answer:

> As the name imples, MimeTypeGuesser is just "guessing" the MimeType.
>   From my experience it is really difficult to get the right mime type
>   for files coming from many different sources, so you will need to end
>   up opening the range of types that you accept. If you are worried
>   about security , you can always apply more tests to those files, for
>   example use a docx parser to verify that it is a real docx file

Comment: This should actually be posted by @CarlosGranados. Is he available to do so?